# Ajax Обновление нескольких блоков

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Вопрос в следующем. Есть простой код в котром ajax обновляет блок div. Как сделать что бы можно было обновлять более одного блока на странице?

Сейчас обновляется блок с id=content обработчик temp.php . Хочется что бы ещё обновлялся блок с id=content-1 него будет свой обработчик temp-1.php

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>HOME</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script>  
        function show()  
        {  
            $.ajax({  
                url: "temp.php",  
                cache: false,  
                success: function(html){  
                    $("#content").html(html); 
    }
             });      
        }  
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            show();  
            setInterval('show()',100);  
        });   
    </script>
    
</head>
    <body>
          <div class="r">
          <p class="r1">Температура  дома</p>
          <div class="r2>
          <div class="r3" id="content"></div> 
          <div class="r3"> C<sup>o</sup></div>
          </div>
          </div>
        
          <div class="r">
          <p class="r1">Температура на балконе</p>
          <div class="r2>
          <div class="r3" id="content-1"></div> 
          <div class="r3"> C<sup>o</sup></div>
          </div>
          </div>       
   </body>
</html>
```

КОД TEMP.PHP

```html
<?php 
$myFile = "data.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);
echo $theData;
?>
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow! Вы могли бы добавить к вопросу метки `javascript` и `php`, если хотите, чтобы он получил больше внимания.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавь в функцию

```
$.ajax({  
                url: "temp-1.php",  
                cache: false,  
                success: function(html){  
                    $("#content-1").html(html); 
                }
             });
```

Хотя лучше бы я сделал через один обработчки и он возвращал Json. После этого ты его парсишь и вставляешь в нужные блоки.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Жаль не могу плюсануть вас.  Всё работет ))) Результат можно посмотреть тут  arduino.zhodinovel.com.